# Type Casting BindingList from DataGridView Datasource

Tags: c#, casting, datasource, bindinglist

I have interface IDoc and an abstract class that implements it named Doc. I then have a class named BookDoc that inherits from Doc and another class JournalDoc that also inherits from Doc.

Now what I would like to do is bind either a `BindingList<BookDoc>` or `BindingList<JournalDoc>` to a custom DataGridView. I then want to be able to access an Errors property the they both inherit from the Doc class.

semi working Example:

```
var dataSource = this.DataSource as BindingSource;

BindingList<BookDoc> tempBookDocs = dataSource.DataSource as BindingList<BookDoc>;

var Docs = new List<IDoc>();

foreach (var tempDoc in tempBookDocs)
{
    Docs.Add(tempDoc);
}
```

The above example works and i get a list of Docs that is populated and i can access the Errors property but still have to hard code the type of list that was originally bound.

What i would like to do is something like this though I'm not sure it is possible.

```
var dataSource = this.DataSource as BindingSource;

BindingList<Doc> Docs = dataSource.DataSource as BindingList<Doc>;
```

This gives me a null Docs list though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4.0, you can take advantage of [covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) using `IEnumarable<>`:

```
IEnumarable<Doc> tempBookDocs = dataSource.DataSource as IEnumarable<Doc>;

var Docs = new List<IDoc>();

foreach (var tempDoc in tempBookDocs)
{
    Docs.Add(tempDoc);
}
```

If you're using .NET 3.5, you can use LINQ [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) extension method:

```
IEnumarable<Doc> myDocs = ((IEnumarable)dataSource.DataSource).OfType<Doc>();

var Docs = new List<IDoc>();

foreach (var tempDoc in myDocs)
{
    Docs.Add(tempDoc);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Much does exactly what i needed it to